# Find the index of item in array where the item contains a substring

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm writing html with javascript dynamically and store it in an array.

```
["<div id="findme_u_13" name="someone" ><span style="… id="null" width="15px" height="15px"/></a></div>", "<div id="findme_u_1106" name="anotherone" ><span s… id="null" width="15px" height="15px"/></a></div>"]
```

After that i want to be able to determine the index of the complete item that holds ie findme_u_somenumber.

I've looked at the indexof method but that obviously doesn't do it.
The reason why i want to store the html is to speed up the appending to the Dom and skip the creation the Html over and over again.
Is there a quick way to search through ie 1000 strings in an array and return the index of the string containing the value?

Comment: Of course I can devise something that will do exactly what you ask, but why store HTML in an array. There should be a nicer way to do it?

Comment: Why doesn't a for loop work?

Comment: The html is needed to form the onelinelist in a chat-application. When i client connects it gets (by design) the list of users that are currently in the login-channel. When a user switches channel the complete node containing the html is removed and new html is written and appended. When there are a lot of users in the channel i find it takes to long. So my idea was to store the initial Bulk of users in an array and use that. Changes are then made by socket-update messages to add/delete nodes from that array. Hope that i'm somewhat clear? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a simpler way of doing it and just concatenated the strings off html in a variable and then appending it as innerHTML to a domnode.
Much quicker then looping, creating and appending. ;-)

For the selection of the u_number i found out that it is a static number belonging to a client so selecting is easy.

Thanks though for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the HTML inside the array in a `node` and use a queryselector to get it out. This way you can traverse that bit of HTML in memory. This gives a solution to the question:

```js
var html_array = ['<div id="findme_u_13" name="someone" ><span id="null" width="15px" height="15px"></span></div>', '<div id="findme_u_1106" name="anotherone" ><span id="null" width="15px" height="15px"></span></div>'];

function retrieveIndexFromArray(indexNumber)
{
  var elementFound = -1; //
     var div = document.createElement("div"); //create an in-memory node.
     div.innerHTML = html_array.join(""); //add the string to it.
     var element = div.querySelector("#findme_u_"+indexNumber)
     if (element) //test if the string matches the index requested.
     {
         elementFound = element; //save the element

     }
console.log(element)
  return element; //return the element;
}

document.body.innerHTML += "Found element: " + retrieveIndexFromArray(13).outerHTML.replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;"); //result
```

I do want to know why your are storing html in an array. Why not store a reference in an array and use an HTML template to fill it with the correct data.

Comment: The number behind _u is a number assigned on account creation by autoincrement in a database. edit.... i see now that it does what i want i think. I'm gonna look now if it speeds up things.

Comment: When the values are in singlequotes your code works. The html however is placed in the array with doublequotes.

Answer (score 0):

`indexOf` certainly does work. I think the problem is that you're using double quotes to separate your elements when you should be using single quotes (because of the double quotes in the HTML). This returns the index, or false.

```
function findThis(arr, id) {
    for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
       if (arr[i].indexOf(id) > -1) return i;
    }
    return false
}

findThis(arr, 'findme_u_1106') // 1
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xtaet2pj/)

Comment: Found my thinking error: mixed `Array.prototype.indexOf` with `String.prototype.indexOf`, you are using the latter.